# Simple calculator that respects operation priority

Tags: java, calculator

I wrote the code for a calculator, but it's not respecting the priority of operation. What do I need to change? The program doese't have to support `()`.
When you run it, you should enter a number, then a sign and continue reading numbers and signs until user input is `=`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a,c ;
 char sgn;

 c = sc.nextInt();

do{     
    sgn = sc.next().charAt(0); 
    if (sgn=='=') break;

    a = sc.nextInt();
 switch (sgn) {
       case '+' : c += a; break;    
       case '-' : c -= a; break;
       case '*' : c *= a; break;
       case '/' : c /= a; break;
       }
   }while(sgn!='=');
  System.out.println(c);
 }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. An easy one is to transform your infix expression to postfix and then use a stack to compute the result.

Comment: You need to...implement the logic for operator precedence, which is far too broad a question for SO. Hint: You cannot do that for standard infix expressions without storing the input and then analyzing it afterward, because of things like `4 + 3 * 2`.

Comment: @AlexisC.question changed, I hope now is easy to understand what I wanted to ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, solved by myself

```
int prod = sc.nextInt();
int sum = 0;
char ops;

do {
    ops = sc.next().charAt(0);
    switch (ops) {
    case '*':
        prod *= sc.nextInt();
        break;
    case '/':
        prod /= sc.nextInt();
        break;
    case '+':
        sum += prod;
        prod = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    case '-':
        sum += prod;
        prod = -sc.nextInt();
        break;
    }
} while (ops != '=');

System.out.println(sum + prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to respect the priority of operations, you must wait for the user to finish typing the complete equation, and only then start the computation. 
You can try it by yourself. if you look at someone writing an equation , you can't start doing calculation until he's done writing the complete equation (or calculation).

For example, I start writing 2+2...

Now, you can say "Well, this is 4"

But then i continue writing 2+2*3

Now, if you have calculated "2+2=4" and now you see the "*3", you can't tell if it was 1+3*3 or 3+1*3 or 0+4*3, or even (-96)+104*3

Also, you are missing the implementation of brackets, which is important and users will expect you to have it.

After you have done that, I suggest you try an implementation using [Binary Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), as I find it more intuitive.

Here's a [hint](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-pics/firsttree.jpg) on how to do it.

Comment: I was creating a simple program only